# Hibernate deletes all content of table on startup, even though hbm2ddl.auto is set to update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I don't have any errors, the tables just empty when the program starts.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```xml
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:data/javabot.db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="org.laconfrerie.discord.javabot.entities.ToxicMember" />
        <mapping class="org.laconfrerie.discord.javabot.entities.BannedUser" />
        <mapping class="org.laconfrerie.discord.javabot.entities.Vote" />
        <mapping class="org.laconfrerie.discord.javabot.entities.AutoRole" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

persistence.xml

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="javabot">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

SessionFactory creation:

```java
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
final ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(registry);
```

Additional note: I use JDA, and the table content is deleted right when JDA finished loading

Comment: Change line in session factory to :  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

Comment: @Mateusz well yes but no, the goal hbm2ddl.auto is to automatically create tables, and validate just checks if they are there